# Telnet into host and execute commands

Tags: java, exec, telnet

I am using the Apache commons-net lib to telnet into a PC. 
After I am done connecting to this server, I want to be able to execute commands on it(server). 
What is the best way to achieve this in Java?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work remotely, but this is how you would run system commands locally [by using _Runtime.exec()_]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: But wouldn't the Runtime instance be that of the machine I am running this application from, not what I telnet into?

Comment: I was gonna say you should _ssh_ rather than _telnet_ until I saw you mentioned a PC :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off using [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to telnet to  your remote machine and execute the commands.  Checkout the [examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/) sections - it has everything you need.

Comment: I can't seem to find an example that demonstrates telnet - but why would you want to use telnet over ssh?

Comment: It seems the OP is trying to connect to a PC, maybe it doesn't have ssh?

Comment: I don't want it to ask for a username and password. It doesn't have to be that secure. So,telnet was my obvious choice.

Comment: I guess I don't know - I mean, your requirements seem a little loose.  Is this for school?  Why is requiring username and password bad?  If not, just use the user public key and set StrictHostKeyChecking=false

Comment: @AmirAfghani the link you offered, is not actually a telnet example, it doesn't work with telnet it just works with SSH, as you can see in the example it has used port 22 which is for SSH, telnet port is 23.